# How max.poll.interval.ms and max.poll.records works in Kafka as a consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I have these settings:

- have 20 messages in a partition,
- max.poll.interval.ms = 10000 (10 secs),
- max.poll.records = 6,
- processing a message takes 1 second.

At the first poll() the consumer will get 6 messages, processing it in 6 seconds and commit it
at the end.

At this point a rebalancing happens, or the consumer just calls poll() again?

Let's assume it calls poll() again:

get the next 6 messages, it also takes 6 seconds to processing it, so it will go over max.poll.interval.ms.

If I'm not mistaken the consumer at the end will not be able to commit the last 6 messages, so after the rebalance the consumer will get these 6 messages again, right?

If this is the case I believe set the max.poll.records to the lowest as possible is the best option, or maybe commit after every message processing (set the partition offset = offset + 1) is viable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering, I would like to highlight few consumer client configurations.

[max.poll.interval.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.poll.interval.ms)

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

[enable.auto.commit](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_enable.auto.commit)

> If true the consumer's offset will be periodically committed in the background.

[auto.commit.interval.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.commit.interval.ms)

> The frequency in milliseconds that the consumer offsets are auto-committed to Kafka if enable.auto.commit is set to true.

Consumer receives 6 messages after first poll(), and spends 6 seconds processing them. So there will be no rebalancing at the end of processing since the maximum delay (poll interval) is 10 secs and it is not breached.

After processing, poll() is called again and poll interval timer is reset; consumer will get 6 new records again and process repeats.

Note: Assuming `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true`

By any chance if consumer is unable to process received messages within `max.poll.interval.ms` (10 secs in this case), then there are two cases

1. `enable.auto.commit` is set to `false` or `auto.commit.interval.ms` is higher than `max.poll.interval.ms` and you don't commit offsets before processing - In this case, rebalance occurs and new consumer will get the messages again. Only in this case, you have to consider changing `max.poll.records` and/or `max.poll.interval.ms`
2. `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true` or `auto.commit.interval.ms` is lower than `max.poll.interval.ms` - In this case, rebalance occurs but new consumer will not get the 6 messages again since consumed offsets are committed already